# Python - decorators based execution

Tags: python

I am trying to execute all the functions with common decorator without calling all the functions. For example

```
@run 
@v1
def test1():
  #do something

@run
@v1
@v2
def test2():
 #do something

@run
@v2
def test3():
 #do something

@run
def test4():
 #do something
```

I want to executes the test functions based on the decorators like @run executes all 4 tests. @v1 executes only first two. How can I do that? Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: You certainly can't do it the way you've written it; the commas are not valid Python and neither is e.g. `v1.2`.

Comment: Yes, I cannot use comma, I can add new decorator in next line.
I am trying to execute the tests based on the decorator

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the decorator to "register" your functions in a list:

```
_to_run = [] # list of functions to run
def run(func):
    _to_run.append(func) # add the decorated function to the list
    return func

@run
def test1():
    print('test1')
    return 1

@run
def test2():
    print('test2')

def test3():
    print('test3')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for test in _to_run: # iterate over registered functions
        x = test()
        print('Returned:', x)
```

On the other hand, you could as well create this list explicitly, without decorators.